# I keep getting an error in my code and can't figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The error:

```
File "D:/Users/44749/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Game.py", line 271, in draw_messages
    text_height = helper_text_height(Constants.FONT_MESSAGE_TEXT) TypeError: helper_text_height() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I'm trying to display some text on screen however I keep getting this error and I can't seem to solve it anyone have any idea on what I could do to solve this?

```
import pygame

#game files
import Constants


#  _____  _____ _______ _____  _    _  _____ _______
# / ____|/ ____|__   __|  __ \| |  | |/ ____|__   __|
#| (___ | |       | |  | |__) | |  | | |       | |
# \___ \| |       | |  |  _  /| |  | | |       | |
# ____) | |____   | |  | | \ \| |__| | |____   | |
#|_____/ \_____|  |_|  |_|  \_\\____/ \_____|  |_|

class struc_Tile:
    def __init__(self, block_path):
        self.block_path = block_path               #Creates a place where the player cant walk to
        self.explored = False


#  ____  ____       _ ______ _____ _______ _____
# / __ \|  _ \     | |  ____/ ____|__   __/ ____|
#| |  | | |_) |    | | |__ | |       | | | (___
#| |  | |  _ < _   | |  __|| |       | |  \___ \
#| |__| | |_) | |__| | |___| |____   | |  ____) |
# \____/|____/ \____/|______\_____|  |_| |_____/

class obj_Actor:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name_object, sprite, creature = None, ai = None):
        self.x = x #Map address
        self.y = y #Map address
        self.sprite = sprite

        self.creature = creature
        if creature:
            creature.owner = self

        self.ai = ai
        if ai:
            ai.owner = self

    def draw(self):
        is_visible = libtcodpy.map_is_in_fov(FOV_MAP, self.x, self.y)

        if is_visible:
            SURFACE_MAIN.blit(self.sprite, (self.x*Constants.CELL_WIDTH, self.y*Constants.CELL_HEIGHT))







#  ____ ___  __  __ ____   ___  _   _ _____ _   _ _____ _____ ____
# / ___/ _ \|  \/  |  _ \ / _ \| \ | | ____| \ | | ____|_   _/ ___|
#| |  | | | | |\/| | |_) | | | |  \| |  _| |  \| |  _|   | | \___ \
#| |__| |_| | |  | |  __/| |_| | |\  | |___| |\  | |___  | |  ___) |
# \____\___/|_|  |_|_|    \___/|_| \_|_____|_| \_|_____| |_| |____/

class com_Creature:

    #Creatures have health, and can damage other objects by attacking them. can also die
    def __init__(self, name_instance, hp = 10, death_function = None):

        self.name_instance = name_instance
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.death_function = death_function



    #self.x + dx]
    #Where you are + Where you want to go
    #Are you able to move to the palce you want to go
    def move(self, dx, dy):

        title_is_wall = (GAME_MAP[self.owner.x + dx][self.owner.y + dy].block_path == True)

        target = map_check_for_creatures(self.owner.x + dx, self.owner.y + dy, self)

        for object in GAME_OBJECTS:
            if (object is not self.owner and
                object.x == self.owner.x + dx and
                object.y == self.owner.y + dy and
                object.creature):
                target = object
                break

        if target:
            print (self.name_instance + " Attacks " + target.creature.name_instance + " for 5 damage!")
            target.creature.take_damage(5)

        if not title_is_wall and target is None:
            self.owner.x += dx
            self.owner.y += dy



    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.hp -= damage
        print (self.name_instance + "'s health is " + str(self.hp) + "/" + str(self.maxhp))

        if self.hp <= 0:

            if self.death_function is not None:
                self.death_function(self.owner)
#TODO class com_Item:

#TODO lass com_Container:


#    _    ___
#   / \  |_ _|
#  / _ \  | |
# / ___ \ | |
#/_/   \_\___|

class ai_test:

    #Once per turn, execute
    def take_turn(self):
        self.owner.creature.move(libtcodpy.random_get_int(0, -1, 1),libtcodpy.random_get_int(0, -1, 1))

def death_monster(monster):

    print (monster.creature.name_instance + " is dead ")

    monster.creature = None
    monster.ai = None



# __  __          _____
#|  \/  |   /\   |  __ \
#| \  / |  /  \  | |__) |
#| |\/| | / /\ \ |  ___/
#| |  | |/ ____ \| |
#|_|  |_/_/    \_\_|
def map_create():
    new_map = [[ struc_Tile(False) for y in range (0, Constants.MAP_HEIGHT)] for x in range(0, Constants.MAP_WIDTH) ]

    #Creates the actual path block so if its set to tru you cant walk there if its set to false you can walk there
    #Also this is where you create new walls floors etc etc
    new_map[10][10].block_path = True
    new_map[10][15].block_path = True

    for x in range(Constants.MAP_WIDTH):
        new_map[x][0].block_path = True
        new_map[x][Constants.MAP_HEIGHT-1].block_path = True

    for y in range(Constants.MAP_HEIGHT):
        new_map[0][y].block_path = True
        new_map[Constants.MAP_WIDTH-1][y].block_path = True

    map_make_fov(new_map)

    return new_map

def map_check_for_creatures(x, y, exclude_object = None):

    target = None

    if exclude_object:

        for object in GAME_OBJECTS:
            if (object is not exclude_object and
                object.x == x and
                object.y == y and
                object.creature):
                target = object
                break

            if target:
                return target
    else:
        
        for object in GAME_OBJECTS:
            if (object is not exclude_object and
                object.x == x and
                object.y == y and
                object.creature):
                target = object
                break

            if target:
                return target

def map_make_fov(incoming_map):
    global FOV_MAP

    FOV_MAP = libtcodpy.map_new(Constants.MAP_WIDTH, Constants.MAP_HEIGHT)

    for y in range(Constants.MAP_HEIGHT):
        for x in range(Constants.MAP_WIDTH):
            libtcodpy.map_set_properties(FOV_MAP,x ,y,
                not incoming_map[x][y].block_path, not incoming_map[x][y].block_path)


def map_calculate_fov():
    global FOV_CALCULATE

    if FOV_CALCULATE:
        FOV_CALCULATE = False
        libtcodpy.map_compute_fov(FOV_MAP, PLAYER.x, PLAYER.y, Constants.TORCH_RADIUS, Constants.FOV_LIGHT_WALLS,
            Constants.FOV_ALGO)


# ____  ____      ___        _____ _   _  ____
#|  _ \|  _ \    / \ \      / /_ _| \ | |/ ___|
#| | | | |_) |  / _ \ \ /\ / / | ||  \| | |  _
#| |_| |  _ <  / ___ \ V  V /  | || |\  | |_| |
#|____/|_| \_\/_/   \_\_/\_/  |___|_| \_|\____|

def draw_game():

    global SURFACE_MAIN

    #Clear the surface -- if you dont clear it, it will just draw over the last surface
    SURFACE_MAIN.fill(Constants.COLOR_DEFAULT_BG)



    #Draw the map
    draw_map(GAME_MAP)


    #Draw all Objects
    for obj in GAME_OBJECTS:
        obj.draw()

    draw_debug()
    draw_messages()

    #Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

def draw_map(map_to_draw):

    for x in range(0, Constants.MAP_WIDTH):
        for y in range(0, Constants.MAP_HEIGHT):

            is_visible = libtcodpy.map_is_in_fov(FOV_MAP, x, y)

            if is_visible:

                map_to_draw[x][y].explored = True

                if map_to_draw[x][y].block_path == True:
                    #draw wall
                    SURFACE_MAIN.blit(Constants.S_WALL, ( x*Constants.CELL_WIDTH, y*Constants.CELL_HEIGHT))
                else:
                    #draw floor
                    SURFACE_MAIN.blit(Constants.S_FLOOR, (x * Constants.CELL_WIDTH, y*Constants.CELL_HEIGHT))

            elif map_to_draw[x][y].explored:
                if map_to_draw[x][y].block_path == True:
                    # draw wall
                    SURFACE_MAIN.blit(Constants.S_WALLEXPLORED, (x * Constants.CELL_WIDTH, y * Constants.CELL_HEIGHT))
                else:
                    # draw floor
                    SURFACE_MAIN.blit(Constants.S_FLOOREXPLORED, (x * Constants.CELL_WIDTH, y * Constants.CELL_HEIGHT))

def draw_debug():

    draw_text(SURFACE_MAIN, "fps:" + str(int(CLOCK.get_fps())) , (0,0), Constants.COLOR_WHITE, Constants.COLOR_BLACK)

def draw_messages():

    to_draw = GAME_MESSAGES

    text_height = helper_text_height(Constants.FONT_MESSAGE_TEXT)

    start_y = Constants.MAP_HEIGHT*Constants.CELL_HEIGHT - (Constants.NUM_MESSAGES * text_height)

    i = 0

    for message, color in to_draw:

        draw_text(SURFACE_MAIN, message, (0, start_y + (i * text_height), 0), color, Constants.COLOR_BLACK)

        i += 1



def draw_text(display_surface, text_to_display, T_coords, text_color, back_color = None):
    ### this function takes in some text, and displays it on the referenced surface.

    text_surface, text_rect = helper_text_objects(text_to_display, text_color, back_color)

    text_rect.topleft = T_coords

    display_surface.blit(text_surface, text_rect)


#  _    _      _
# | |  | |    | |
# | |__| | ___| |_ __   ___ _ __
# |  __  |/ _ \ | '_ \ / _ \ '__|
# | |  | |  __/ | |_) |  __/ |
# |_|  |_|\___|_| .__/ \___|_|
#               | |
#               |_|

def helper_text_objects(incoming_text, incoming_color, incoming_bg):

    if incoming_bg:
        Text_surface = Constants.FONT_DEBUG_MESSAGE.render(incoming_text, False, incoming_color, incoming_bg)

    else:
        Text_surface = Constants.FONT_DEBUG_MESSAGE.render(incoming_text, False, incoming_color)

    return Text_surface, Text_surface.get_rect()

def helper_text_height():

    font_object = font.render("a", False, (0, 0, 0))
    font_rect = font_object.get_rect()

    return font_rect.height



#  _____          __  __ ______
# / ____|   /\   |  \/  |  ____|
#| |  __   /  \  | \  / | |__
#| | |_ | / /\ \ | |\/| |  __|
#| |__| |/ ____ \| |  | | |____
# \_____/_/    \_\_|  |_|______|

def game_main_loop():

    game_quit = False

    while not game_quit:

        #player action definition
        player_action = "no-action"

        #handle player input
        player_action = game_handle_keys()

        map_calculate_fov()

        if player_action == "QUIT":
            game_quit = True

        elif player_action != "no-action":
            for obj in GAME_OBJECTS:
                if obj.ai:
                    obj.ai.take_turn()


        #Draw game
        draw_game()

        CLOCK.tick(Constants.GAME_FPS)
    #Quit game
    pygame.quit()
    exit()


def game_initialize():

    global SURFACE_MAIN, GAME_MAP, PLAYER, ENEMY, GAME_OBJECTS, FOV_CALCULATE, CLOCK, GAME_MESSAGES

    pygame.init()

    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    SURFACE_MAIN = pygame.display.set_mode( (Constants.MAP_WIDTH*Constants.CELL_WIDTH,
                                             Constants.MAP_HEIGHT*Constants.CELL_HEIGHT ) )

    GAME_MAP = map_create()

    GAME_MESSAGES = []

    game_message("test message", Constants.COLOR_WHITE)

    FOV_CALCULATE = True

    creature_com1 = com_Creature("Human")

    PLAYER = obj_Actor(1, 1, "Human", Constants.S_PLAYER, creature = creature_com1,)


    creature_com2 = com_Creature("Thief", death_function = death_monster)

    ai_com = ai_test()

    ENEMY = obj_Actor(15, 15, "Bandit", Constants.S_ENEMY,
                      creature = creature_com2, ai = ai_com)
    #Where the enemy is placed


    GAME_OBJECTS = [PLAYER, ENEMY]

def game_handle_keys():
    global FOV_CALCULATE
    #Get player input
    events_list = pygame.event.get()

    # Process input
    for event in events_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return "QUIT"

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                PLAYER.creature.move(0, -1)
                FOV_CALCULATE = True
                return "player-moved"

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                PLAYER.creature.move(0, 1)
                FOV_CALCULATE = True
                return "player-moved"

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                PLAYER.creature.move(1, 0)
                FOV_CALCULATE = True
                return "player-moved"

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                PLAYER.creature.move(-1, 0)
                FOV_CALCULATE = True
                return "player-moved"
    return "no-action"

def game_message(game_msg, msg_color):

    GAME_MESSAGES.append((game_msg, msg_color))


#EXECUTION CODE
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game_initialize()
    game_main_loop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it, the function `helper_text_height` takes no arguments:

```
def helper_text_height():
    ...
```

But you called it with a parameter in `draw_messages` function:

```
text_height = helper_text_height(Constants.FONT_MESSAGE_TEXT)
```

Maybe what you wanted to do was in the definition of the function:

```
def helper_text_height():

    font_object = font.render("a", False, (0, 0, 0))
    font_rect = font_object.get_rect()

    return font_rect.height
```

You wanted to add a parameter `font` like so:

```
def helper_text_height(font):

    font_object = font.render("a", False, (0, 0, 0))
    font_rect = font_object.get_rect()

    return font_rect.height
```

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to explain to @lownzy how they could correct the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Kingsley, I added some thing from what I understood.